# Selenium>Cucumber: How can I set default param for steps?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I'm new in Cucumber. I've concern that is there any way to strict default param in `testcase.fearture`. 
   For example:

```
And User click Delete on task action
```

And in step definition, my params should be anything because I use `(.*)`. But I want user just put one of 3 values like "Create", "Edit", "Delete". 
   How can I define it in step definition, below is my current code implementation:

```
@And("^User search (.*)on tasklist$")
    public void searchTask(String taskObject) throws Throwable {
        TaskboardPage taskboardPage = new TaskboardPage(sbConnect);
        taskboardPage.searchTask(taskObject);

    }
```

Could I use `@And(User search (?: Create | Edit | Delete) on tasklist)`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Could I use @And(User search (?: Create | Edit | Delete) on tasklist)?

Yes. You can do that:

```
@And("^User search (Create|Edit|Delete) on tasklist$")
    public void searchTask(String taskObject) throws Throwable {
        TaskboardPage taskboardPage = new TaskboardPage(sbConnect);
        taskboardPage.searchTask(taskObject);
    }
```